# How do I batch a request to Compute Engine using the Python Google Cloud Client Libraries?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-client

In the older Google API Client Libraries, you could batch a request to label many instances at once, using `googleapiclient`, `discovery.build("compute", "v1").new_batch_http_request(...)`

With the new, [recommended](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client#other-google-api-libraries) Cloud Client Libraries, you can set labels on one instance with [setLabels](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/setLabels), but I don't see a way to batch these requests.

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/api/how-tos/batch) mentions the batching of requests, but only with a direct HTTPS call, and I would rather use a Python library. This documentation does refer to a Python library, but only the older Google API Client Libraries.

I don't mind using the older Google API Client libraries, but, though they are [officially supported](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client#other-google-api-libraries), they have had, since 2016 at least, severe bugs causing invocation failure. (This is in their SSL implementation, see [1](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/issues/218), [2](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/issues/1118) and [more](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/search?q=socket+timeout&type=issues)). This makes   them impossible to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simply not possible to batch requests with the "Cloud Client Libraries".